# Int array to Flags Enum

Tags: c#

I have the following Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum RoleModel {
  Admin = 1 << 0,
  Editor = 1 << 1,
  Member = 1 << 2
}
```

And I have a list of integers:

```
List<int> = new List<int> { 1, 3 }
```

How can I parse the Ints to the flags enum?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: What do you want to get for `3`.  `Admin | Editor` ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do a cast:

```
RoleModel x = (RoleModel)1;
Debug.Assert(x.HasFlag(RoleModel.Admin));

RoleModel y = (RoleModel)3;
Debug.Assert(y.HasFlag(RoleModel.Editor) && y.HasFlag(RoleModel.Member));
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with LINQ:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 3 };

List<RoleModel> parsedList = 
    list.Select(n => Enum.GetName(typeof(RoleModel), n) ?? String.Empty)
        .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        .Select(s => (RoleModel)Enum.Parse(typeof(RoleModel), s))
        .ToList();
```